# How to retrieve data with the highest version number?

Tags: abap, opensql

I use sql below to join DRAT & DRAP.

```
SELECT * INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF WA_DOC_LOG
FROM DRAP
INNER JOIN DRAT ON DRAP~DOKNR = DRAT~DOKNR
AND DRAP~DOKAR = DRAT~DOKAR
WHERE DRAP~DOKNR IN S_DOKNR
AND DRAP~DOKAR IN S_DOKAR
AND DRAP~DOKST IN S_DOKST
AND DRAP~DATUM IN S_DATUM.
```

But when I display, I just want to display the record with highest version number (DRAP~DOKVR). What is the possible ways to eliminate the records with lower version?

Comment: Maybe aggregate functions can help you there. I would sort the table afterwards with dokvar ascending and then just read the first entry

Answer (score 0):

I would probably [off-load this to the application server](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/ABAPDELETE_DUPLICATES.htm):

```
SORT documents BY dokar doknr dokvr DESCENDING. " careful with doktl!
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM documents COMPARING dokar doknr.
```

Using SQL to achieve this might be possible, but I'd be very careful since this might turn out to be rather expensive unless done right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * 
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE WA_DOC_LOG
  FROM DRAP AS d
 INNER JOIN DRAT AS t
    ON d~DOKNR = t~DOKNR
   AND d~DOKAR = t~DOKAR
 WHERE d~dokvr = ( SELECT max( dokvr ) FROM drap ).
```

Although, it is not very efficient, but functional yet. You should consider performance on your concrete system yourself.